# Why low impedance for gate drive design

Tags: gate-driving

Why is it desired to have a low impedance in gate drive circuits? What is do you mean by having a low impedence sourcing and sinking capabilities?

Comment: Do you know what it means to drive a gate?

Comment: Searching for this will reveal a lot of information. What is unclear in that information?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no effort or research prior to posting.

Comment: @Asmyldof It's definitely not off topic, but I agree with the rest of your premise.

Comment: @NickJohnson It's the only vote-path where I can give a custom reason with my current rep, AFAIK. It will then be shown as "voted to be off topic", so I chose to keep that part of the default explanation. It's the system, I'm using it as best I knew how.

Answer (score 6):

A MOSFET has a very high gate resistance because the gate is physically insulated from the other terminals on the device. This means that under DC conditions it doesn't draw any current, making you think it wouldn't need much to drive the gate. However, the gate has a large surface area over the drain-source channel and this introduces quite a lot of capacitance between the gate-drain and gate-source. When you try to switch the MOSFET on and off, you must charge and discharge this capacitance from your gate driver. To do this quickly you need a gate driver that can source a lot of current for short periods of time - in other words, one that has a low impedance.

The reason you want the MOSFET to switch quickly is because it is during the transition between states that it dissipates the most energy. In the off state there is no current, while in the on state the drain-source voltage is very low, minimising the power dissipated (Vds x Ids) in both situations. Ensuring the MOSFET spends as little time as possible outside of these two states is critical to making high efficiency motor drives and switching power converters.